# How to Inject a runtime created string to another class using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

At the startup, I am creating a string according to the database type in class A. Then I want to inject that string value to class B after the setBitAndSqlExpression() function is called. After the injection I want to use that variable in Class B. Class B is executed if the user makes a request after run time init.

Note that they are in different packages. I cannot pass them via the constructor.

```
class A { //code first enters here
public String BITAND_SQL_EXPRESSION;

    public void setBitAndSqlExpression() {
        try {
            String driverName = dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getDriverName();
            if (driverName.contains("PostgreSQL")) {
                BITAND_SQL_EXPRESSION = "%s" + "::INTEGER" + " & %s = %s";
            } else {
                BITAND_SQL_EXPRESSION = "BITAND (%s,%s) = %s";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Driver cannot be found. Setting operations will not work correctly.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
class B { //enters here if only user makes a request after class A creation.
public String BITAND_SQL_EXPRESSION; // want to use the value at class A

public B(

...//codes and constructors.
}
```

Comment: From your code class A and B are not spring managed beans correct? And why you cannot pass the result from `A#setBitAndSqlExpression` to B via constructor? Show us how you use those two classes in your code please

Comment: *I cannot pass them via the constructor* - create setter and getters

Comment: Class A has Annotation base spring configurations, and class B does not have. basically I'm confused how to reach from B to A.

Comment: Edit your question and post your code please dont describe but post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a factory method possible for you ?
It would be in the package of the B class :

```java
public interface IB {
    methodA();
    methodB();
}
```

```java
class B implements IB{ //enters here if only user makes a request after class A creation.
    public String BITAND_SQL_EXPRESSION; // want to use the value at class A

public B(

...//codes and constructors.
}
```

```java
public final class BFactory {
    public static IB create(String sqlExpression) {
        return new B(sqlExpression);
    }
}
```

Then in the package of class A you could call this factory

```java
BFactory.create(BITAND_SQL_EXPRESSION);
```

A would depend of an interface and not the B implementation.